# R find top n results of column operation on aggregate operation per column over dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

Say I have a dataframe called RaM that holds cumulative return values.  In this case,  they literally are just a single row of cumulative return values along with column headers, but I would like to apply the logic to not just single row dataframes.

Say I want to sort by the max cumulative return value of each column, or even the average, or the sum of each column.

So each column would be re-ordered so that the max cumulative returns for each column is compared and the highest return becomes the 1st column with the min being the last column

then say I want to derive either the top 10 (1st 10 columns after they are rearranged), or even the top 10%.

I know how to derive the column averages, but I don't know how to effectively do the remaining operations.  There is an order function, but when I used it, it stripped my column names, which I need.  I could easily then cut the 1st say 10 columns, but is there a way that preserves the names? I don't think I can easily extract the names from the unordered original dataframe and apply it with my sorted by aggregate dataframe. My goal is to extract the column names of the top n columns (in dataframe RaM) in terms of a column aggregate function over the entire dataframe.

something like

```
top10 <- getTop10ColumnNames(colSums(RaM))
```

that would then output a dataframe of the top 10 columns in terms of their sum from RaM

Here's output off RaM

```
> head(RaM,2)
                 ABMD        ACAD       ALGN        ALNY        ANIP      ASCMA        AVGO        CALD        CLVS       CORT
2013-01-31 0.03794643 0.296774194 0.13009009  0.32219178  0.13008130 0.02857604  0.13014640 -0.07929515  0.23375000  0.5174825
2013-02-28 0.14982079 0.006633499 0.00255102 -0.01823456 -0.05755396 0.07659708 -0.04333138  0.04066986 -0.04457953 -0.2465438
                  CPST         EA         EGY        EXEL FCSC       FOLD        GNC         GTT      HEAR          HK         HZNP
2013-01-31 -0.05269663 0.08333333 -0.01849711  0.01969365    0  0.4179104 0.07992677 0.250000000 0.2017417  0.10404624 -0.085836910
2013-02-28  0.15051595 0.11443102 -0.04475854 -0.02145923    0 -0.2947368 0.14079036 0.002857143 0.4239130 -0.07068063 -0.009389671
                  ICON        IMI        IMMU        INFI        INSY        KEG        LGND        LQDT         MCF        MU
2013-01-31  0.07750896 0.05393258 -0.01027397 -0.01571429 -0.05806459 0.16978417 -0.03085824 -0.22001958  0.01345609 0.1924290
2013-02-28 -0.01746362 0.03091684 -0.20415225  0.19854862  0.36849503 0.05535055  0.02189055  0.06840289 -0.09713487 0.1078042
                NBIX      NFLX       NVDA       OREX       PFPT          PQ       PRTA         PTX        RAS        REXX        RTRX
2013-01-31 0.2112299 0.7846467 0.00000000 0.08950306 0.06823721  0.03838384 -0.1800819  0.04387097 0.23852335 0.008448541  0.34328358
2013-02-28 0.1677704 0.1382251 0.03888981 0.04020979 0.06311787 -0.25291829  0.0266223 -0.26328801 0.05079882 0.026656512 -0.02222222
                  SDRL      SHOS         SSI        STMP         TAL         TREE        TSLA      TTWO        UVE       VICL
2013-01-31  0.07826093 0.2023956 -0.07788381  0.07103175 -0.14166875 -0.030504714  0.10746974 0.1053588  0.0365299  0.2302405
2013-02-28 -0.07585546 0.1384419  0.08052150 -0.09633197  0.08009728 -0.002860412 -0.07144761 0.2029581 -0.0330408 -0.1061453
                   VSI       VVUS        WLB
2013-01-31  0.06485356 -0.0976155 0.07494647
2013-02-28 -0.13965291 -0.1156069 0.04581673
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data or use an example built-in dataset so we can understand what you want. We don't know what your return values look like and it's unclear what happens with multiple rows. See [how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I provided sample via output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using the first section of your sample data to illustrate. You can `gather` up all the columns so that we can do summary calculations more easily, calculate all the summaries by group that you want, and then sort with `arrange`. Here I ordered with the highest sums first, but you could do whatever order you wanted.

```r
library(tidyverse)
ram <- read_table2(
  "ABMD        ACAD       ALGN        ALNY        ANIP      ASCMA        AVGO        CALD        CLVS       CORT
0.03794643 0.296774194 0.13009009  0.32219178  0.13008130 0.02857604  0.13014640 -0.07929515  0.23375000  0.5174825
0.14982079 0.006633499 0.00255102 -0.01823456 -0.05755396 0.07659708 -0.04333138  0.04066986 -0.04457953 -0.2465438"
)
summary <- ram %>%
  gather(colname, value) %>%
  group_by(colname) %>%
  summarise_at(.vars = vars(value), .funs = funs(mean = mean, sum = sum, max = max)) %>%
  arrange(desc(sum))
summary
#> # A tibble: 10 x 4
#>    colname    mean     sum    max
#>    <chr>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 ALNY     0.152   0.304  0.322 
#>  2 ACAD     0.152   0.303  0.297 
#>  3 CORT     0.135   0.271  0.517 
#>  4 CLVS     0.0946  0.189  0.234 
#>  5 ABMD     0.0939  0.188  0.150 
#>  6 ALGN     0.0663  0.133  0.130 
#>  7 ASCMA    0.0526  0.105  0.0766
#>  8 AVGO     0.0434  0.0868 0.130 
#>  9 ANIP     0.0363  0.0725 0.130 
#> 10 CALD    -0.0193 -0.0386 0.0407
```

If you then want to reorder your original data frame, you can get the order from this summary output and index with it:

```r
ram[summary$colname]
#> # A tibble: 2 x 10
#>      ALNY    ACAD   CORT    CLVS   ABMD    ALGN  ASCMA    AVGO    ANIP
#>     <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1  0.322  0.297    0.517  0.234  0.0379 0.130   0.0286  0.130   0.130 
#> 2 -0.0182 0.00663 -0.247 -0.0446 0.150  0.00255 0.0766 -0.0433 -0.0576
#> # ... with 1 more variable: CALD <dbl>
```

Created on 2018-08-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: this worked.  I modified my code seamleslly inserting a data.frame(RaM) because I didn't have a data frame haha.  Thank you so much, add this as the answer and I'll accept it.  I am on my way to some good portolio investing

Comment: This is an answer?

Comment: yes, thank you.  I've been knee deep in r for the past few days, this helped tremendeously!  I owe you infinite internet gratitude and I truly appreciate it.  I was doing the operation by hand and was wondering how for the life of me, I was able to do exactly what I needed and even feed the list of names back into a portfolio optimizer.